# VBA Code to filter and get values from csv to excel worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, csv, excel-365

I need to write VBA for a csv that will be regularly updated.Im stuck in a loop of errors and idk what to do.

**I need to implement an excel 365 macro that :**

**Opens a csv file with the link : "C:\Users\Dev-01\Desktop\Automated Reports\Approved to Funded Loans\Docs Out to Funded.csv"**

**The function will have two parameters the filter and the row number**

**Then extract two values :**

**First value is the number of rows based on the filter in column 2 .**

**Second value is the addition of all values in column 6 of the filtered data .**

**After extracting the data, put the values in the workbook “ Dash Board “ in column 3 and 5 and the row**

**These are the corresponding rows numbers after the strings to call the function with:**

Condition Review 7

Final Underwriting 8

Pre-Doc 9

Clear To Close 10

Docs Ordered 11

Docs Drawn 12

Docs Out 13

Docs Back 14

Funding Conditions 15

```
Sub GetTotalsFromCSV()

    ' File path and column setup (adjust as needed)
    Const filePath As String = "C:\Users\Dev-01\Desktop\Automated Reports\Approved to Funded Loans\Docs Out to Funded.csv"
    Const filterColumn As Integer = 2
    Const totalColumn As Integer = 6

    ' Array of filter values with corresponding row numbers
    Dim filterValuesAndRows As Variant
    filterValuesAndRows = Array( _
        Array("condition review", 7), _
        Array("final underwriting", 8), _
        Array("Pre-doc", 9), _
        Array("clear to close", 10), _
        Array("docs ordered", 11), _
        Array("docs drawn", 12), _
        Array("docs out", 13), _
        Array("Docs back", 14), _
        Array("funding conditions", 15) _
    )

    ' Open and read CSV data
    Dim data As Variant
    data = ReadCSVFile(filePath)

    ' Iterate through filter values and apply filtering and calculations
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(filterValuesAndRows) To UBound(filterValuesAndRows)
        Dim filterValue As String
        filterValue = filterValuesAndRows(i)(0)

        Dim targetRow As Long
        targetRow = filterValuesAndRows(i)(1)

        ' Filter data based on current value
        Dim filteredData As Variant
        filteredData = FilterData(data, filterColumn, filterValue)

        ' Calculate total for filtered data
        Dim filteredTotal As Double
        filteredTotal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(filteredData, totalColumn)

        ' Calculate number of filtered rows
        Dim filteredRowCount As Long
        filteredRowCount = UBound(filteredData, 1) - LBound(filteredData, 1) + 1

        ' Write total number of rows and filtered total to separate cells
        Cells(targetRow, 3).Value = filteredRowCount  ' Number of filtered rows
        Cells(targetRow, 5).Value = filteredTotal       ' Filtered value total

    Next i

End Sub

' Helper function to read CSV data
Function ReadCSVFile(filePath As String) As Variant
    Dim fso As Object, file As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set file = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath, ForReading)
    ReadCSVFile = Split(file.ReadAll, vbCrLf)
    file.Close
End Function

' Helper function to filter data
Function FilterData(data As Variant, filterColumn As Integer, filterValue As String) As Variant
    Dim filteredArray() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    ReDim filteredArray(LBound(data) To UBound(data), LBound(data, 2) To UBound(data, 2))

    For i = LBound(data) To UBound(data)
        If data(i, filterColumn) = filterValue Then
            For j = LBound(data, 2) To UBound(data, 2)
                filteredArray(k, j) = data(i, j)
            Next j
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next i

    ReDim Preserve filteredArray(LBound(filteredArray) To k - 1, LBound(filteredArray, 2) To UBound(filteredArray, 2))
    FilterData = filteredArray
End Function
```

It should be a simple thing to do i tried multiple codes online and help from associates. This is the last thing i ended up with.

Comment: What's the error number and text? and on which line?

Comment: `ReadCSVFile` returns a single-dimension array but you're trying to use it like a 2D array.  At no point does your code split each line of the CSV on comma...

Comment: I would open the CSV as a file in Excel - then you can use the built-in filtering etc without needing to write code to implement that.

Comment: If the CSV is simple structure - first line is column headers - can probably use PowerQuery. Or VBA can open recordset and use CopyFromRecordset method - about 10 lines of code. Both approaches can aggregate data. Make sure cells are formatted as Number before populating values.

Comment: I would definitely use Powerquery for this. can you post sample source + expected result?